# How to strip words from a column value if the value contains specific substrings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have row values as such:

```
         ID     MyColumn      
0        A      "Best Position 3 5"
1        B      "Healthy (unexpired)
2        C      "At-Large"
3        D      "Run 2 Position 1"
4        E      "Hello"
4        E      "None"
4        E      "Tomorrow"
```

I want to scan this table for any rows that contain substrings "Position", and then for those rows keep only the first instance of an int. I have the Lambda / regex for taking  the first instance of an int in a value:

```
...str.replace(r'\D+', '').str.split()
```

but I'm not sure how to apply it on the condition of substring appearances.

Resulting set:

```
         ID     MyColumn      
0        A      "3"
1        B      "Healthy (unexpired)
2        C      "At-Large"
3        D      "2"
4        E      "Hello"
4        E      "None"
4        E      "Tomorrow"
```

Comment: `Healthy (unexpired)` has no numbers in it.  What should the output be in this case?  Maybe include the full expected output here.

Comment: Hey good callout, neglected to give an accurate description. I updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for first integer with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and last replace by original non matched values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
mask= df['MyColumn'].str.contains('Position|unexpired', case=False)
df['MyColumn']=(df['MyColumn'].mask(mask,df['MyColumn'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False))
                              .fillna(df['MyColumn']))
print (df)
  ID              MyColumn
0  A                     3
1  B  "Healthy (unexpired)
2  C            "At-Large"
3  D                     2
4  E               "Hello"
4  E                "None"
4  E            "Tomorrow"
```

Comment: Hey so I should have been more clear in my OP, but I want to keep the string as-if if the keyword is not found. I updated OP so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 2):

We might be able to use `str.replace` here with a smart regex:

```py
regex = '.*?(\d+).*(?:Position|unexpired).*|.*?(?:Position|unexpired).*?(\d+).*'
df['new'] = df.loc['MyColumn'].str.replace(regex, '\1\2', case=False)
```